# Registering Custom Intent for SiriKit in my ios app

Tags: ios, siri, sirikit

According to the [Apple online documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH11-SW1), SiriKit supports only specific domains for now.

Our app is a gift based app that you can send different kind of gifts like birthday gift, mother day gift etc. We want to make a custom Siri domain (like gift domain) which recognizes a voice command like

**"Hey Siri send a gift to Jack with 'my AppName'"** 

and then it calls a web service with a specific encoded key and starts sending gift operations without my app openning.


Is it possible?


I also wonder that for Payment domain you need to say **"Hey Siri send money ...."** for Siri to recognizes the payment command. 
Do you know which voice commands needed for Siri to recognize the domain type? Is there a Siri voice command list in the Apple online documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to extend your app with Siri kit. And need to register intents for your app in info.plist,as shown in image below.

[image]

You can find more details on below links:

1) [How To Extend Your iOS App With SiriKit](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/extending-your-ios-app-with-sirikit-fd1a7ef12ba6)

2) [Apple's Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/creating_an_intents_app_extension)

Comment: As a result should I need to use one of the existing intent domain like messaging or payment or etc?

Comment: Yes, as of now there are four intents available 1) messaging, 2)payments, 3)ride booking and 4)workouts only.

Comment: Do you think that I can make Siri to open my app when user says "Hey Siri share a flower with myAppName" under the messaging intent domain or not?

Comment: Yes, Share you can handle as send. Please refer https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/extending-your-ios-app-with-sirikit-fd1a7ef12ba6 you will able to solve your problem.